# delphi - get form class from a frame code

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I get the classtype of the owner form of a frame from the frame code, and to convert that type to TFormClass? 
I know that I need to register the form class, so I can get it with [GetClass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.GetClass), but there I get stuck.

Comment: I don't understand. `Owner.ClassType` doesn't work?

Comment: @NGLN, Owner is Not necessarily a TForm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class type of the host form is obtained like this:

```
HostFormClassType := TFormClass(GetParentForm(Self).ClassType);
```

Here when I write `Self` I take that to be your frame. Although you said "owner", I suspect that what you really mean is the form on which the frame resides. That's usually the same thing as the frame's owner, but not always.

There's no need to register anything or call `GetClass`.

The only slight wrinkle with this is that `GetParentForm` could return something derived from `TCustomForm` rather than `TForm`. So the cast in the above code has potential to be incorrect. You would deal with that by including a runtime test.

```
var
  ClassType: TClass;
....
ClassType := GetParentForm(Self).ClassType;
Assert(ClassType.InheritsFrom(TForm));
HostFormClassType := TFormClass(ClassType);
```